# Erratic behaviour of unity and some programs

Tags: 16.04, unity

It's easier to see it first and then explain it:

[image: GIF of the problem]

- When I switch to a program with tabs to any of the previous ones, it instantly travels to the last one (like in Chrome in the GIF).
- Drop-downs close automatically and hover tool-tips disappear after a split second.
- Moving the mouse over any shortcut of an open program in the launcher automatically switches to that program, without clicking it. (Showing it with settings/Chrome in the GIF)

I initially thought this was a GTK bug but I'm not sure anymore since it's not happening in some GTK programs, i.e. Firefox.

What I've tried:

- Reinstall unity
- Reinstall xorg

I am at a complete loss as to what is causing this and I'd prefer not to reinstall Ubuntu. Any suggestions?

Comment: Okay, I solved it (at least for now), but I have absolutely no idea what caused it or what fixed it. It certainly isn't an Ubuntu problem. I've booted a live usb and the problem was persistent there too. I've unplugged the keyboard, thinking it might be the issue, but it didn't seem to do anything. I've powered down the PC and reset the MoBo and it's gone.